# Logging into iCloud on a Network Managed user account

Tags: mac, icloud

If I log into a Mac at my uni, then I log on as a network user, so none of my files are actually stored on the Mac and I can log on to any machine and anyone can log into their account on this Mac.

Is it safe to log into iCloud in this case, as in noone else will be able to access it after I log out? Will it try and sync my entire iCloud Drive to this Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't add your personal iCloud account to a shared Mac. It can be done but you would need to set it up to not sync anything to the Mac and by doing that you are using iCloud in the way it was really designed to be used. Plus you would need to sign out each time for security. You would be better off accessing your iCloud account on a web browser.